# Sheloshim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred thirty?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: What do you mean?
Sheloshim Umatayim = 230 (we say: "Matayim Ushloshim").

Comment: See the comment stream on Echad Ve'esrim: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/1123/echad-veesrim-mi-yodeya I decided to use the Mishnaic form used in the Hagada, to go with the "Mi Yodeya" song this is based on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Four beitzim (of 57.6 cc each, according to R' Avraham Chaim Naeh) equal 230 cc. This, according to [various](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/?id=31446) [online sources](http://www.karnash.co.il/index.asp?catID=15879&siteLang=3), is the amount of pas haba'ah bekisnin (baked goods that are bread-like but not fully so, e.g., pizza) that requires washing and recital of hamotzi.

Answer (score 2):

[At the end of the first chapter of Masechet Sanhedrin in the Mishna](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%90_%D7%95):

How many shall a city contain that it shall be fit for a supreme council? One hundred and twenty families. R. Nehemiah, however, maintains: **Two hundred and thirty**--so that each of them should be the head of ten families, as we do not find in the Bible rulers of less than ten.